# Python unit test last test detection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing

Is there any way to check if there is another unit test to be executed? Since the user can pick and choose which unit tests he/she wants to be run, I want to call a function in the very last test case that is run (of the very last suite that is run) , so is there an equivalent of next() that I can check to see if there are any more test cases to be run? Or is there an attribute (or presence of an attribute) that I can use to detect if this is indeed the last test to be run?

I know that I can overwrite the tearDown() and tearDownClass() functions, but tearDownClass() still will call at the end of every test suite.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures), it states that “ Class and module level fixtures are implemented in TestSuite. When the test suite encounters a test from a new class then tearDownClass() from the previous class (if there is one) is called, followed by setUpClass() from the new class.” 
 How does it detect that it has encountered a test from a new class? And can I leverage this to find if there is still a test to be run?

Comment: Unittest shpuld be made to be independent of each other and their order of ececution. So, what is the idea behind this?

Comment: I opened up a socket and I want to close the connection at the very end of the unit tests, so I'm struggling to find out how I can do so, since my unit tests rely on this connection staying open until the very end

Comment: Then, they are no unittests. A unittest should create the required conditions before the test and reset them afterwards. Also external resources like sockets should be mocked.

Comment: So if I am running a series of unittests to test the responses that I get back from a server, I should be opening and closing the connections per unittest?  Is there a way to call a function just once after all the unit tests have executed as a work around until I can rewrite all my test cases?

Comment: A unit test does not test responses from servers, it tests for example how your code reacts to a specific response of a server by simulating it. Testing a server is an *integration test* and integration tests should also be independent, but one actual test can consist of several steps.

Comment: Oh, I see - so what I've written is an integration test; is it not in good practice to write integration tests using the python unittest library? But given that my integration test is currently not independent, is there a way to check if the current unittest is the last one as a quick fix for now?